Shared dependencies are still generated in both remote and shell app in @angular-architects/module-federation
Both shell app and remote app has angular_core package in the build bundle, even after adding them in shared: {} webpack config. Is it expected?
Shell app webpack config
'@angular/core': {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    '@angular/common': {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    '@angular/router': {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    ...shareAll({
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    }),
    'ui-components': {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: '>=0.0.1 <=1.0.0',
    },
  },
  sharedMappings: ['shared-components']

Remote app webpack config
 "@angular/core": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    "@angular/common": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    "@angular/router": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    "@angular/common/http": {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    },
    ...shareAll({
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto'
    }),
    'ui-components': {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: '>=0.0.1 <=1.0.0',
    }
  },
  sharedMappings: ['shared-components']

I was expecting the shared packages should be bundled only once in shell app but was included in remote's bundle as well which causes duplicate bundles
